# Neo4j python driver - it is very slow to iterate through the results

Tags: python, performance, neo4j

I am trying to get a million relationships from neo4j to make some analysis in python, but it takes a lot of time to iterate through the results.

Below is a very simplified query to give you an example. I took the time to iterate through 250.000 records and the result was 1 minute aprox. I tried returning only the attributes that I want, checking if the amount of data had some impact, but the result was almost the same.

Is it normal? Am I not taking into account something important? How can I do it faster?

Thanks in advance

```py
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, auth=(user, password))

query = """
        MATCH (u:User)-[r:was_at]->(p:Place)
        RETURN u, p, r
        LIMIT 250000
    """

session = driver.session()
result = session.run(query)

i = 0
for record in result: 
    i += 1
```

```
CPU times: user 57.2 s, sys: 736 ms, total: 58 s
Wall time: 1min 7s
```

**Edit:**

**Please note that it takes one minute to iterate the results without doing anything:**

```
i = 0
for record in result: 
    i += 1
```

Is that normal?

**Answers to the comments:**

Yes, the `was_at` relationship type only exist between User and Place nodes.

The goal is to create an Igraph instance of the network. Each node has some attributes, you can see them in the following example:

```
<Record 
  u=<Node id=0 labels={'User'} properties={'followers': 274, 'screen_name': 'PASTORMAURICIOR', 'name': 'PASTORMAURICIOROJAS', 'verified': 'False', 'statuses': 2434, 'created_at': 'Sat May 28 00:03:02 +0000 2011', 'id': '306492469', 'friends': 330}> 
  p=<Node id=982894 labels={'Place'} properties={'id': '8866e09315fffff'}> 
  r=<Relationship id=1556326 nodes=(
     <Node id=0 labels={'User'} properties={'followers': 274, 'screen_name': 'PASTORMAURICIOR', 'name': 'PASTORMAURICIOROJAS', 'verified': 'False', 'statuses': 2434, 'created_at': 'Sat May 28 00:03:02 +0000 2011', 'id': '306492469', 'friends': 330}>, 
     <Node id=982894 labels={'Place'} properties={'id': '8866e09315fffff'}>
    ) type='was_at' properties={'date': neotime.DateTime(2017, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>>
```

When I return only the relationship, the nodes don't include the attributes, which are needed:

```
<Record r=<Relationship id=1556326 nodes=(
  <Node id=0 labels=set() properties={}>, 
  <Node id=982894 labels=set() properties={}>
 ) type='was_at' properties={'date': neotime.DateTime(2017, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>>
```

I create the igraph instance by constructing a list of edges, a list of nodes attributes and a list of edge attributes.

I am running these queries in an instance of Neo4j 3.5.14. My machine runs Ubuntu on a Intel Celeron @ 1.60 with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: By "get a million relationships", do you literally mean that you just want the relationships and not the nodes? Also, does the `was_at` relationship type only exist between `User` and `Place` nodes?

Comment: What is the platform for running the query and iteration? How complex is the computation(s) in the iteration? More clarity in the question would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the question to answer your comments. Please note that it takes one minute only to iterate the results, increasing a counter. I also have explained what I want to do in case you know a better way of doing it. Let me know if there is more information needed

Answer (score 0):

I found this link:

https://community.neo4j.com/t/performance-problem/1676

There, an user found that having DateTime attributes makes the process really slower.

In my case, after converting the datetimes to epoch the time improved to 20sec, when I return only some attributes. 
Therefore, I suppose there is still room for improvement.

I'll take a look and update this answer with the findings.